# How to consider if for loop is completed?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
    console.log('interval cleared');
}
```

The above code will log 99999 times "interval cleared". But how to log if for loop is completed?

```
if(for loop is completed){
  console.log('interval cleared');
}
```

Comment: Why not just `console.log` immediately after the loop?

Comment: Why don't you just use if(i == 99998){//code here}

Comment: @Nick That should be if(i == 99999 ) ???

Comment: `for` loops are sync, so it's completed once you get out of the block.

Comment: @C-linkNepal No, in the last loop var i will have the value 99998, you won't get 99999 because it has to be lower than 99999.

Comment: Humm, I just realised!

Comment: What's the point of this script?

Comment: Perhaps you need to study up on what a for loop is. Obviously you cannot say the loop is finished inside the loop, because you would be in the loop, even if it's the last interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop is synchronous and the code within your loop, as written, is also synchronous.  Your for loop will complete before any code after it executes.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
    console.log('interval cleared');
}

console.log("all intervals cleared");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will stop only when `i` has a value higher or equal to 99999, so this means after the loop is over `i` will here actually have a value of 99999 since you increment it at the end of each iteration. Now, that means that if `i` is exactly equal to your upper boundary minus one (99998) you can tell that you wont loop another time (except if you modify `i` with a lower value inside your loop).

Which means you can do this

```
var upperBoundary = 99999;
for (var i = 1; i < upperBoundary; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
    if (i === upperBoundary - 1) {
        // last iteration code
        console.log('All intervals cleared');
    }
}
```

But this is an alternative to a simpler code:

```
var upperBoundary = 99999;
for (var i = 1; i < upperBoundary; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
}


// note that i has the same value as upperBoundary
console.log('All intervals cleared');
```

---

In js and in many other programming languages a for loop is structured in 3 parts (each separated by a semicolon):

1. Boundary initialization (for example `var i = 0`)
2. Condition which determines whether you will loop again or
   not (i.e. `i < 99999`)
3. Incrementing (which is done each
   time after the body of the loop is executed)

You could translate it to a code with while loop for example:

```
// initialization
var i = 0;
// condition
while(i < 99999) {
    // loop body

    // incrementing
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Nick imagine this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
    if(i==99998) console.log('all intervals cleared');
}
```

In fact, the 99999 interval will not be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Loop starts

```
int count = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
window.clearInterval(i);
count++;
console.log('interval cleared');
}
console.log('Loop ended:' + count);
```